# Formatting numbers with hugrex function in huxtable

Tags: r, string-formatting, huxtable

Function `huxreg` in the `huxtable` package automatically recognises numbers and formats them as predefined in the `number_format = "%.3f"` option. I would like to report confidence intervals in my report and use the **CI95:** prefix. Unfortunately, the numerical part of the prefix is automatically formatted and the prefix looks like **CI95.000**.

Let's consider following example:

```
library(huxtable)
data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), x=rnorm(10))
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data)

huxreg(fit,
     ci_level = 0.95,
     error_pos = "below",
     error_format = "CI95: ({conf.low}, {conf.high})" )
```

[image]

Is there any way to get the CI95 as intended? I have tried numeric to character conversions with no success. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not optimal, you could perhaps add `, number_format = c("%.3f", "%.3g", "%.3f", "%.3g")` to your `huxreg` call to specifically affect the formatting of the CI95 rows of your table (or save the output as an object and then modify the attribute elements that define the formatting of those lines, e.g. do `attr(res, "number_format")[[13]] <- "%.3g"`, etc.). Other than that I could only think of somehow modifying the underlying `glue` transformer that transforms the entire string and leaves all numeric elements with the same formatting.

Comment: Thank you for listing several methods. The first one is the most convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Another hack is to pass a list containing a function into `number_format`:

```r
    library(huxtable)
    library(dplyr)
    data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), x=rnorm(10))
    fit <- lm(y ~ x, data)
    
    leave_95_alone <- function (n) ifelse(n == 95, as.integer(n), sprintf("%.3f", n))
    
    huxreg(fit,
             ci_level = 0.95,
             error_pos = "below",
             error_format = "CI95: ({conf.low}, {conf.high})" 
           ) %>% 
           set_number_format(c(3,5), 2, 
             list(leave_95_alone)
           )
```